# Apple Keyboard / Trackpad using too much power?

Tags: keyboard, power-management, macbook, trackpad

If I open powertop my keyboard / trackpad seems to be using 10+ watts of power at 100% usage at all times.  I feel like this may be a bit excessive.  Is it normal for the keyboard / trackpad on my hardware (MacBook Pro 8,2) to be using so much power or am I just being silly here?

Thanks

```
10.3 W    100.0%                      Device         USB device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad (Apple Inc.)
```

Comment: I get 13W on MBP 9,1 running 14.04

Comment: I have the same problem.